# Create source map from typescript api transformation

Tags: typescript, preprocessor

I'm using typescript API to create a custom syntax file preprocessor, just like svelte and vue do.

So, I input my custom file with a custom syntax and use `ts.transform` function to walk through the AST tree and change what I need to change.

But what I didn't find in ts docs is, how can I generate source maps from my input file string to the output result string?

```
const sourceFile = ts.createSourceFile(
  "index.ts",
  fileContent, // file input string
  ts.ScriptTarget.ESNext,
  false,
  ts.ScriptKind.TSX
);
const result = ts.transform(sourceFile, [transformer]); // my custom transformer function
const resultStr = printer.printFile(result.transformed[0]); // the output file string
// how to get sourcemaps for "resultStr"?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stumbled up on this yesterday as i had the same issue when using `ts.transform`. So I looked up how ts-jest was able to generate the same when running in isolatedModules.

After looking into ts-jest code base found that if we use `ts.transpileModule` instead of `ts.transform`, the result output includes source map as well.

Here is what i used which returned source maps as well (with TS 4.7.x),  -

```
const transformedOutput = ts.transpileModule(sourceText, {
    fileName: sourcePath,
    transformers: {
        before: [transformer]
    },
    compilerOptions: {
        target: ts.ScriptTarget.ES2015,
        module: ts.ModuleKind.ESNext,
        isolatedModules: true,
        sourceMap: true
    }
});
console.log('Transformed Code - \n', transformedOutput .outputText);
console.log('Transformed sourcemap - \n', transformedOutput .sourceMapText);
```

Here is a link to ts-jest codebase with this usage - https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/blob/main/src/legacy/compiler/ts-compiler.ts#L256

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on typescript and started using `magic-string` package that creates a cool sourcemap for you with no headaches.

https://github.com/Rich-Harris/magic-string